# Term ' ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run this in one line using the "Run" command:

```
powershell -NoExit ; Get-ChildItem -Recurse -force -Include *.ost \\PcHostname\c$\users -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" | ls | Select-Object Name, @{Name="GigaBytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1GB}}
```

but I get this error:

```
GigaBytes : The term 'GigaBytes' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:137
+ ... t Name, @{Name=GigaBytes;Expression={$_.Length / 1GB}}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (GigaBytes:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The code works on a started Powershell window without `powershell -NoExit ;`.

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Just tried and didn't get any such error.

Comment: @Rahul I mean, Start->Run "PasteTheCode" but I get the error... Did you tried the same steps?

Comment: That way you will get error most probably. Instead do start->run->powershell. once shell window comes up .. paste the coe and run. it will be fine

Comment: @Rahul I need to change the hostname on the fly, another software is involved, thats why I looking that way. I want to believe theres something to get it work as I need:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way command line arguments are tokenized through "Run", you need to either escape the double quotes around `GigaBytes` (using the `\` escape character) or substitute them with single quotes. Either of these two `Select-Object` commands should work:

```
Select-Object Name, @{Name=\"GigaBytes\";Expression={$_.Length / 1GB}}
```

or

```
Select-Object Name, @{Name='GigaBytes';Expression={$_.Length / 1GB}}
```

This is because anything wrapped in double quotes will be interpreted as a single argument.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094897/3396598) answer for a more detailed explanation as to how command line arguments are tokenized through "Run".

Comment: thanks, finally I discovered pass parameters but THAT is help full.